# How to change the textbox size in twig template

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I want to change the text box input size in twig template and i am not able to do it.

I am trying this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.age, { 'size': '5' }) }}
```

and its not working, but this is working:

```
{{ form_widget(form.age, { 'id': 'myid' }) }}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand) you should try to use `attr` property

```
{{ form_widget(form.age, { 'attr': {'size': '5'} }) }}
```

Comment: Hey any idea how to change the size of a text area?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the quotation marks around '5'.